# Deploy AWS SageMaker endpoint for Hugging Face embedding model

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

I would like to deploy a huggingface text embedding model endpoint via aws sagemaker.

Here is my code so far:

```
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.huggingface.model import HuggingFaceModel

# sess = sagemaker.Session()
role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()

# Hub Model configuration. <https://huggingface.co/models>
hub = {
  'HF_MODEL_ID':'sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L12-v2', # model_id from hf.co/models
  'HF_TASK':'feature-extraction' # NLP task you want to use for predictions
}

# create Hugging Face Model Class
huggingface_model = HuggingFaceModel(
    env=hub, # configuration for loading model from Hub
    role=role, # iam role with permissions to create an Endpoint
    py_version='py36',
    transformers_version="4.6", # transformers version used
    pytorch_version="1.7", # pytorch version used
)

predictor = huggingface_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge"
)

data = {
"inputs": ["This is an example sentence", "Each sentence is converted"]
}

result = predictor.predict(data)
print(len(result[0]))
print(result[0])
```

While this does deploy a endpoint successfully, it does not behave the way it should.
I expect for each string in the input list to get a 1x384 list of floats as output.
But instead i get 7x384 lists for each sentence.
Did I maybe use the wrong pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

The output you are seeing is the default that is produced by that model. If you would like to shape output for as you expect you can either do this on the client side (once output is received) or also attach an inference.py script that implements functions that will shape your output: specifically the predict_fn and output_fn functions.

Example: https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/tree/main/sagemaker/17_custom_inference_script/code

```
def model_fn(model_dir):
  # Load model from HuggingFace Hub
  tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_dir)
  model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_dir)
  return model, tokenizer

def predict_fn(data, model_and_tokenizer):
    # destruct model and tokenizer
    model, tokenizer = model_and_tokenizer
    
    # Tokenize sentences, preprocessing etc ....
```